# Check if there is only 1 character difference between two strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, difference

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate whether the difference in two strings is exactly 1 character (or lack of it)

The function should cover the following cases:

```
STRIN1G / STRIN2G
ONE TOO THREE / ONE TWO THREE
NATALI / NATALIE
ASTRING / STRINGB
```

The `levenshtein` function (where you would check if it returns 1) would work in all cases but it wouldn't cover the last case.

Comment: You may share what you tried yet and then suggestions can be provided where you can improve. Please read [What type of questions should I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm probably won't work for all situations, but meets your given examples and should get you closer to your ultimate goal. Have a look at [`similar_text`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) which is more expensive than `levenshtein` but more flexible. Here we'll just make an adjustment based on the varying lengths of the strings, in cases where one is a complete substring of the other.

demo: https://3v4l.org/IZ943

```
$strings = [
    'STRIN1G' => 'STRIN2G',
    'ONE TOO THREE' => 'ONE TWO THREE',
    'NATALI' => 'NATALIE',
    'ASTRING' => 'STRINGB',
];

foreach ($strings as $string => $variant) {
    $length = strlen($string);
    $adjustment = abs($length - strlen($variant));
    $matching = similar_text($string, $variant);
    var_dump($length - $matching + $adjustment);
}
```

> ```
> int(1)
> int(1)
> int(1)
> int(1)
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I needed. Honestly I thought a solution to this problem would have to be very obvious and straightforward but it appears it is not as quite

Comment: Edit: it would not however cover the case: 'SOME STRING' => 'SOME STRNG'

Comment: yep, you're right, that won't work. possibly some diff between the two, or worse re-implement levenshtein so that you can count the insert and delete pair as 1 point together, or 1 point separately. I don't have time right now to dig into that, but it's an interesting problem.